# Does "tribute" passive count twice if spell is aoe?

Tags: league-of-legends

Say I go Kayle support, buy spellthief's edge, and I hit both enemies with one autoattack using E's splash damage.

Would it work that way?

Comment: doesn't it have a CD?

Comment: It's applied for each champ. Means for 10 secs you can't apply it again to the first target, but you can do it to your next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelltheif's edges mechanics are a bit tricky. The 10 second internal CD is independent for each enemy champion. If you upgrade the item to [Frostfang](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frostfang) or [Frost Queens Claim](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Queen%27s_Claim) it will also allow it to proc on abilities. It's internal cool down for abilities is separate from auto attacks, which again are independent for each champion. This means that you can get two tributes from **each** enemy every 10 seconds. One from your auto attacks and one from your abilities.